# Rewire lattice with probability 0.1 in R

Tags: r, igraph

I have a lattice with 100 nodes and 10 neighbors constructed in the following way:

```
d <- as.directed(graph.lattice(100, 0, nei=10, directed=FALSE, circular=TRUE))
```

Now I would like to rewire it with probability 0.1

IF I use rewire() it requires me to set 'niter' instead of probability.

How can I choose the value of niter so that it corresponds to a probability of 0.1?

Comment: @Arun: the package is `igraph`

Comment: I would like to create a small world network from the lattice by changing some of the edges

Comment: Why not use the function that was made for this reason, `watts.strogatz.game`? But if you don't like it because of some reason, try `rewire.edges`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment by @Gabor, use the `rewire.edges` function:

```
d <- as.directed(graph.lattice(100, 0, nei=10, directed=FALSE, circular=TRUE))

d2 <- rewire.edges(d, 0.1)
```